# Install Etherpad into subdirectory

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy, etherpad

I managed to get Etherpad up and running using [this Etherpad installation instruction](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/installing-etherpad-on-debianubuntu/).

It runs at `http://localhost:9000/` on my server and is delivered on Apache via Reverse Proxy and SSL to `https://www.example.com/`.

This is all running fine, but as Etherpad is not my only application I want it to be called via `https://www.example.com/etherpad/`. How can I manage this?

I tried to change the `ProxyPass` commands to

```
ProxyPass /etherpad/ http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse /etherpad/ http://localhost:9000/
```

which made it available at `/etherpad/` directory, but all ressources within it are still delivered from `/` (root directory). Within the `/etc/etherpad/etherpad.local.properties` config file I did not find any relevant setting.

How can I tell Etherpad to live within a subdirectory? I cannot use another subdomain as I would not have SSL there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue by switching to [Etherpad-Lite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite). Not quite the same functionality, but enough for me.

Etherpad-Lite uses relative directories like `../scripts/script.js` instead of absolute directories (Etherpad: `/scripts/script.js`).

Answer (score 2):

[See the Etherpad reverse proxy documentation](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy#with-ssl-enabled-requiring-authentication-and-allowing-nice-urls)

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@example.org
        ServerName etherpad.example.org
        ServerSignature Off
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/etherpad_access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/etherpad_error.log
        ErrorLog syslog:local2

        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
            # the following allows "nice" urls such as https://etherpad.example.org/padname
            # But, some users reported issues with this
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule /p/*$ https://etherpad.example.org/ [NC,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/locales/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/locales.json
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/p/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pluginfw/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascripts/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/socket.io/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ep/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/minified/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ro/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jserror
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon.ico
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt
        RewriteRule ^/+(.+)$ https://etherpad.example.org/p/$1 [L]

            ProxyVia On
            ProxyRequests Off
            ProxyPass / http://etherpad.internal.example.org:9001/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://etherpad.internal.example.org:9001/
            ProxyPreserveHost on
            <Proxy *>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
            </Proxy>
        </IfModule>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I did not manage to get that working, also it does not really move all data into subdirectories. I switched to Etherpad-Lite which uses relative paths.